# AWS Pipeline is not creating S3 triggers for Lambda due to permission limitation

Tags: java, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to create S3 triggers attached with my AWS Lambda using terraform. The IAM attached with my codepipeline is not able to attach the roles with my lambda, even though I have given it administrative access. Here is the AWS Codepipeline output:
[image]

here is my lambda.tf code:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "java_lambda_function" {
  runtime          = "${var.lambda_runtime}"
  filename      = "${path.module}/../target/code.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_archive.output_base64sha256}"
  function_name = "java_lambda_function"
  handler          = "${var.lambda_function_handler}"
  timeout = 900
  memory_size = 256
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  depends_on   = ["aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_group"]

}

data "archive_file" "lambda_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/../target/handler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
  output_path = "${path.module}/../target/code.zip"
}

#set S3 trigger on AWS Lambda

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "terraform-trigger-s3-bucket"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.java_lambda_function.arn
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.java_lambda_function.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "AWSLogs/"
    filter_suffix       = ".log"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
}
```

here is the role attached with my lambda:

```
   # lambda role
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role_for_lambda" {
  name = "lambda-invoke-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ]
}
EOF
}

# lambda policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy_for_lambda" {
  name = "lambda-invoke-policy"
  path = "/"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "LambdaPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents",
          "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
          "xray:PutTraceSegments",
          "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
EOF
}

# Attach the policy to the role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_for_lambda.arn}"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing lambda execution role? Maybe your lambda don't have access to read changes in S3

Comment: I have edited the question and added the role attached to my lambda. You can see I have given it S3 permissions